# Do dinos gain experience from harvesting?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Namely big resource gatherers like the Ankylosaurus or the Doedicurus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you whack away at trees/rocks for a while you will see the dinos XP going up gradually.

Comment: Note that dinos also passively gain xp while some1 is online near them.